# No puedo enviar correctamente valores con Axios post al backend, proyecto en react con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, tengo un objeto cart, que es un carrito de compras, y necesito obtener los valores de los productos del carrito para enviar por post a mi backend. estoy pensando que desestructurando el objeto cart podría obtener los valores y enviarlos al back, pero no logro conseguir los valores del array products, dentro del objeto cart. Tampoco se si es lo correcto o más optimo, no se me ocurre otra cosa, ¿me podrían dar una mano por favor?

```
Este es el componente en el front desde el que intento obtener los datos para enviar 
al backend.
    
const Cart = () => {
    
const publicKey = "--------------------";
    
    
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
console.log(cart)
    
const {quantity, total} = cart;
console.log("quan: ", quantity)
console.log("tota: ", total)
    
const [mercadopago, setMercadopago] = useState(false);
const [preferenceId, setPreferenceId] = useState(null); 
    
const handleCheckout = async () => {
const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/checkout/payment", {
// datos a enviar para recoger desde el back
});
setPreferenceId(res.data.id);
console.log(preferenceId);
setMercadopago(true); // dispara el checkoutpro
};
```

Comment: Hola. Te recomiendo que para almacenar los productos seleccionados por el usuario, es decir los productos que estarán en el carrito de compras; en un estado global (utilizando useContext), de esa forma podrás acceder más fácilmente a los productos que enviarás. Por otra parte, ¿estás utilizando express para el backend?

Comment: Hola Joshua, si estoy usando express. la idea es recoger desde el body los datos para pasarlos al sdk de Mpago.